# Calculating diagonal lengths and sum in a rhombus with known angle

Tags: geometry, angle

I'm struggling with a math problem that involves finding the diagonal lengths and their sum in a rhombus with a known angle. Here's what I've got so far:

- The rhombus $ABCD$ has sides of length $AB = BC = CD = DA = a$.
- Angle $B$ in triangle $ABD$ is $\varphi$.

I need to find the lengths of the two diagonals and their sum. Can anyone please guide me through the steps to solve this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I was told:

> "If you call the center $X$, then $BX = DX = a \cos(\frac{\varphi}{2})$ and $AX = CX = a \sin(\frac{\varphi}{2})$.
> So the sum of the diagonals is $2a (\sin(\frac{\varphi}{2}) +
> > \cos(\frac{\varphi}{2}))$.
> You might make some progress simplifying an expression of the form
> $\sin\theta + \cos\theta$ by writing it as
> $\sqrt{2}\sin(\theta+\frac{\pi}{4})$."

But I am not sure what it means visually, nor did they motivate why.

Here's the drawing they made, where t is instead the angle instead of $\varphi$:

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**Step #0: Concise definition of $\varphi$**
Define $$\angle ABC=\varphi$$
*(avoiding confusion with diagonal angles).*

**Step #1: Express length of diagonal $e$**
$$e=2a\times \cos(\frac{\varphi}{2})$$
*(diagonal e measures twice the distance from vertex $B$ to center $X$, which itself is given by $a\times \cos(\frac{\varphi}{2})=BX$ and where the argument $(\frac{\varphi}{2})$ is the diagonal angle).*

**Step #2: Express length of diagonal $f$**
$$f=2a\times \sin(\frac{\varphi}{2})$$
*(diagonal f measures twice the distance from vertex $A$ to center $X$, which itself is given by $a\times \sin(\frac{\varphi}{2})=AX$).*

**Step #3: Express the sum $(e+f)$**
$$(e+f)=2a\times \left( \cos(\frac{\varphi}{2})+\sin(\frac{\varphi}{2}) \right)$$

**Step #4: 'Simplify' using trig identities**
With the known and adviced identity
$\cos x+\sin x={\sqrt {2}}\cdot \sin \left(x+{\frac {\pi }{4}}\right)$
or with
$\cos x+\sin x={\sqrt {2}}\cdot \cos \left(x-{\frac {\pi }{4}}\right)\\$,
you can establish that

$$(e+f)=2a\times \sqrt2\times \sin \left(\frac{\varphi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

$$(e+f)=2a\times \sqrt2\times \cos \left(\frac{\varphi}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}\right).$$